# Parse and create an NSAttributedString when an UITextView's text changes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uitextview, nsattributedstring, control-flow

I'm trying to parse certain parts of the string when a user types into an `UITextView` or the `setText:` method is called, and then setting an `NSAttributedString` back into the text view. However in my current implementation this causes an infinite recursive loop. Since setting the new attributed text causes the text to change (and the notification to fire) whereby I then re-parse the text.

Somebody suggested I use some kind of flag, so while i'm parsing and setting the text, I don't keep doing it. Though this doesn't seem like the optimal solution. Here's a snippet of my code...

**CustomTextView.h (UITextView subclass)**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textViewDidChange:) name:NSTextViewTextDidChangeNotification object:self];
```

**CustomTextView textViewDidChange:**

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification;
{
    __block NSString *string = self.text;

    dispatch_async(parserQueue, ^{
        NSAttributedString *parsedString = [self parseAttributesForString:string];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self setAttributedText:parsedString];
        });
    });
}
```

**CustomTextView setText:**

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    [super setText:text];
    [self textViewDidChange:nil];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so first I'd add an observer to the property text instead of subclassing the class and post a notification. Next, I'd just check what class the text object is. I would this by calling `[text isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]`. By calling this you know whether the object needs to get parsed again.

Comment: I'm subclassing because I want to largely wrap all of this logic into a custom view that handles parsing / various other aspects. I'm not sure what benefit the `isKindOfClass` call has?

Comment: Well you'd know whether the object is an nsstring or an nsattributedstring. You wouldn't have to parse a NSAttributedString again.

Comment: However, when the UITextView calls setText, it passes in an NSString (because, thats what its typed to take) so this would be of no use. I assume it calls the `string` method of NSAttributedString.